# limit field's value with value from another table before write

Tags: postgresql, triggers, transactions, postgresql-9.1

Are Postgres `TRIGGER`s transactional by default like (I've read) in MySQL?

I've created a [`TRIGGER` procedure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) that uses a simple `IF` to limit a column's value with a value from another `TABLE` with a subsequent `UPDATE` if the limit is breached.

I'd prefer that to be in one single `TRANSACTION`, but if I wrap the `IF`...`THEN UPDATE` with `BEGIN`...`COMMIT`, it gives error

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 2:         BEGIN;
                     ^
```

Are `TRIGGER`s `TRANSACTION`al by default?  If not, how can a `TRIGGER` be made `TRANSACTION`al?

**code**

This is `ON INSERT OR UPDATE` of `articles`:

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN; /* this first TRANSACTION line causes error */
    IF (NEW.votes_used > (SELECT votes_available FROM vote_totals 
     WHERE vote_totals.user_id = NEW.user_id)) THEN
        UPDATE articles SET votes_used = (SELECT votes_available FROM vote_totals 
         WHERE vote_totals.userID = NEW.user_id) WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id;
    END IF;
    COMMIT; /*last TRANSACTION line */
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

I'd MUCH rather do a `CHECK` or `FOREIGN` to nip this in the bud before the data even gets in, but I don't know how to do it with a `FOREIGN`, and I've read that `CHECK`s can't use subqueries.  I think I read that this is the way to go, but I must disclose that I'm db noob.

Comment: The trigger runs in whatever transaction the firing event was. So any change the trigger applies will be rolled back or committed with the outer rollback or commit. But a trigger is a poor choice when you want to limit the value of a column. Why not use a foreign key constraint or a check constraint

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i tried to do a `CHECK`, but subqueries aren't allowed.  how can I do it with a `FOREIGN` if the values from the other table are variable and linked by another column?  will edit to show...  ty!

Comment: Sorry that is not enough information to give you an answer. The question itself seems quite dubious actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `UPDATE` inside a trigger. You can assign the value to `NEW.votes_used`

Use something like:

```
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.votes_used > (SELECT votes_available FROM vote_totals 
     WHERE vote_totals.user_id = NEW.user_id)) THEN
        NEW.votes_used := (SELECT votes_available FROM vote_totals 
         WHERE vote_totals.userID = NEW.user_id);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Or

```
BEGIN
    NEW.votes_used := LEAST(NEW.votes_used, (SELECT votes_available 
                                             FROM vote_totals 
                                             WHERE vote_totals.userID = NEW.user_id));
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

This must be a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger to work. (And as all `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers it must `RETURN NEW`).

If you want to emulate check constraint with trigger - try something like:

```
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.votes_used > (SELECT votes_available  
                          FROM vote_totals 
                          WHERE vote_totals.user_id = NEW.user_id)) 
    THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not enough votes';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Comment: very cool!  a new trick for the toolbag, tyvm!  is a `FOREIGN` possible like horse said, or is this the best way to go?  (plz excuse my noobity)  that second one is awesome!

Comment: @Gracchus I do not think a foreign key is possible - it can only check for equality. But you can emulate a `CHECK` constraint with a trigger. If a trigger `RAISE EXCEPTION` it aborts the transaction like a regular `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: just want to say thank you so much again for this.  i'm using the last 2 a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are transactional in the sense that their actions can be rolled back. You don't have to do anything to make them work like that.

The syntax error is just that. It's hard to tell you more without seeing the code.

Comment: ty!  so a postgre `TRIGGER` locks everything that it reads & writes until finished?  will edit with more code.

Comment: Not exactly; only writes (or explicit lock calls) cause locking. For more information on how PostgreSQL implements transactions, read about MVCC at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/mvcc.html

Comment: @Gracchus: (It's Postgres, not Postgre) - a trigger won't "lock" anything. All statements executed in the trigger run in the *same* transaction as the statement that fired the trigger. If the firing statement is rolled back so is any change done by the trigger. If the firing statement is committed, so is any change done by the trigger.

Comment: I gotta head to the office. I can heartily recommend you take your design questions to #postgresql on freenode (irc). Very friendly crowd! Else I'll check in later this afternoon.